# How to avoid problems caused by new block-library default CSS rules (wp 6.1.1)

Tags: css, updates

I want to update from 5.8.3 to 6.1.1 but when I test it out locally I see that the default CSS for certain classes and elements has been changed so for example:

```
.wp-block-buttons>.wp-block-button{
     margin: 0;
}
```

When before it was

```
.wp-block-buttons>.wp-block-button {
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0.5em;
     margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

All these rules are in wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver6.1.1. Is there a way to enqueue version 5.8.3 of the block styles instead so it doesn't break my theme? Is there a way to find all the changes so that I can write exceptions where they differ?